# Why doesn't this op-amp schematic work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, single-supply-op-amp, non-inverting

[image]

If I use just the first-stage op-amp it works, but the output from the first stage is 2.5 V. If I give it some signal the output will be 2-3 V. In the second stage I use a voltage divider and the second stage doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gain of both amplifiers is ~1000, so you'll get saturated output from the second op-amp's output.

Thus, it will be +Vcc or 0 at the final output.

If you decrease the feedback resistor 1 MΩ value to fix this, for example, with a 10 kΩ resistor, the voltage dividing circuit will not give the correct 2.5 V.

Because you can't neglect the effect of the feedback resistor, which is similar in size to the divider resistors.
The simplest solution is to use one more op-amp repeater for 2.5 V reference.

Comment: will it work if i change 1k resistors of divider to 1M, and the 1M resistor to 10k? Thanks for previous answer, you amazing, thanks

Comment: Can i change the divider resistor to 2 capacitors? or better is to add op-amp repeater for 2.5 V reference?

Comment: Op-amp repeater is the best. For real scenario, you'd better to use REF3025 like stable reference + Op repeater.

Comment: This circuit wouldn't work particularly well even if the gain were 2

Answer (score 6):

The [TL071](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl071.pdf) series is not particularly well suited for operation from a single 5V supply. Depending on the type, some are 10V minimum recommended, and the ones that are 4.5V minimum recommended supply voltage only have an input range that starts from V- +4V so 2.5V is well outside that range. You also have to consider the output swing.

[image]

A DC gain of 1001 * 668 = 667,000 is quite impractical (you might as well remove both the feedback resistors), but you still would see the output slamming from one rail to the other at a tiny near-zero input voltage if the op-amps were working.

Here is your circuit made with more ideal RRIO op-amps. I've fed it a +/-100mV triangle wave at 10Hz. As you can see, the output slams from 0V to 5V.

Note that if you only give it positive inputs it may or may not just do nothing with the output stuck at +5V because the offset voltage of OA1 could be positive or negative a few mV (read the datasheet).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fshkYo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your +5V power supply voltage is too low for an older TL071.
Your input pin 3 voltage of the first opamp has no DC bias voltage.
The opamps amplify AC **and DC.**
[image: TL071]